# Retrieving value from key/value in ArrayList HashMap<String, String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have stored some values to an ArrayList HashMap like so:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bookDetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("book_author", bookAuthor);
                map.put("book_description", bookDescription);


                bookDetails.add(map);
```

I simply want to be able to retreive the description value and have it displayed in a TextView, how would I go about doing so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
text.setText(bookDetails.get(0).get("book_description"));
```

Instead of call `get(0)` you can of course also iterate over the `bookDetails` Array and get the current iteration counter variable, e.g. `get(n)`

Answer (score 3):

**Is a map really necessary?**

Why not creating a **Book.java object**.

Book object has **2 attributes**:

```
public class Book {

    private String bookAuthor;
    private String bookDescription;

    public String getBookAuthor() {
        return bookAuthor;
    }
    public void setBookAuthor(String bookAuthor) {
        this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
    }
    public String getBookDescription() {
        return bookDescription;
    }
    public void setBookDescription(String bookDescription) {
        this.bookDescription = bookDescription;
    }

}
```

Then you can have a **List of books**.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to change the way you store information.

If your map contains only author and description, an effective way would be to omit ArrayList completely and use only Map.

The Map would be

```
HashMap<String, String> map;
map.put(bookAuthor, bookDescription);
```

Accessing the descriptions would be easier as well:

```
String desc = map.get(bookAuthor);
```

Hope this helps.